# Can $L$ supply models for every theory with a well founded model?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

Does ZFC prove that if a theory has a well founded model, then there must be a model of that theory in $L$?

Comment: Do you mean well-founded model? The consistency of the theory is an absolute statement, by completeness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Per Reveillark's comment, I assume you're asking about the existence of a **well-founded** model in $L$.)*

Yes - as long as the theory itself is in $L$ and countable in $L$.

If $T$ is a theory coded by a real in $L$ (= is in $L$ and countable in $L$), then the statement "$T$ has a countable well-founded model" is $\Sigma^1_2$ with a parameter from $L$. By [Shoenfield absoluteness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness#Shoenfield%27s_absoluteness_theorem), that statement is absolute between $L$ and $V$. And if $T$ has a well-founded model in $V$, $T$ has a countable well-founded model in $V$.

For example, $(\star)\equiv$ "There is a proper class of supercompact cardinals" is definitely incompatible with $\mathsf{V=L}$. However, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves that if there is a well-founded model of $\mathsf{ZFC}+(\star)$ then there is a well-founded model of $\mathsf{ZFC}+(\star)$ which is an element of $L$.

---

It's worth noting that we do need $T$ to (be in $L$ and) be countable in $L$ if we want a well-founded (or even $\omega$-)model. For example, suppose $\omega_1^L<\omega_1$. Then we can whip up a theory $T$ which is basically $\mathsf{KP}$ + $\omega_1^L$-many new constant symbols, which are declared to name distinct natural numbers. In $V$ this theory has a well-founded model, but in $L$ any model of $T$ must be a non-$\omega$-model.

Finally, note that countability is only an issue because we're looking at "nice" models. If $T\in L$ is a first-order theory which $V$ thinks is satisfiable, then $L$ also thinks $T$ is satisfiable - since by the Completeness Theorem the unsatisfiability of $T$ would be witnessed by a finite object (a $T$-proof of $\perp$).